# How to start java app from Maven in non-base project folder?

Tags: java, working-directory, intellij-14, exec-maven-plugin

I'm using **Intellij Idea 14** and start learning embedded Maven installation.
At now Maven compile sources, generate JAR with MANIFEST.MF inside (with 'lib/' prefixes in 'Class-Path') to 'target/', copy dependencies at 'target/lib/' folder, copy folder 'src/main/resources/cfg' to 'target/cfg'.
If i manually go to folder 'target' and start app with 'java -jar app.jar' then it works fine and successfully find folder 'cfg', but if i start app from **Idea** then app triyng to search folder 'cfg' in base project folder.
There is some POM piece:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}\</workingDirectory>
                <mainClass>app.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I looked at **workingDirectory** parameter [ http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html ]. This won't work.
How can i change working folder to 'target'? This is for comfort app develop and run/debug right from **Idea**.
I need to get that result application structure:

- /app.jar
- /cfg
- /cfg/application.cfg

Comment: In Run configurations, you can try changing 'Working Directory' path

Comment: I try to change in "Run/Debug Configurations" / "Parameters" / "Working directory" - add "/target" to the end of the path. But there is Maven error occured: "[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\projects\projectfolder\target). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\projects\projectfolder\target). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory."